# CSS Javascript Popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, shadow

I am upgrading my site and have been trying to switch it over to a flip-page online magazine. I have successfully done this but I have one issue. We have video interviews each month and I am trying to make it so someone can click the image in the flip-page and have a pop-up shadow box come forward with the video.

Initially I just embedded the video into the flip-page which works accept it is having an issue showing up on the page before it is supposed to show up. I am assuming this is a flash or z-indexing issue in the page-flip Javascript.

I have tried numerous JQuery galleries that have this function the last being a shadow box that pops up with nothing more than a rel added to the anchor tag. The problem is that when I add the rel to the anchor tag and you click it, it opens a whole new tab instead of a pop-up window.

Does anyone know of any good anchor or div tag pop-up windows that can showcase a video embedded from YouTube? I have put both example into the flip-page right now. The regular embed is on page 25 and the anchor is on 27. You will notice if you play it on 25 and flip back to 23 it will show over page 23 at times.

http://www.grossmag.com/2013-March/

This is the html for the video box starting with the anchor tag. The div's set around are from the page flip code.

```
<div id="page27" class="music">
<div class="img27">
   <span class="pageNumD right">Page 27 </span>
    <img src="/2013/January/img/xf1.jpg" alt="" title="Gross Magazine January 2013 XFACTOR1 Interview with QBall Wolf" border="0">
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2gD1shLW2T0" rel="vidbox" title="caption"><img src="/2013/January/img/xf1.jpg" alt="" title="Gross Magazine January 2013 XFACTOR1 Interview with QBall Wolf" border="0"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the js that came with the videobox

```
var Videobox = {

init: function (options) {
    // init default options
    this.options = Object.extend({
        resizeDuration: 400,    // Duration of height and width resizing (ms)
        initialWidth: 250,      // Initial width of the box (px)
        initialHeight: 250,     // Initial height of the box (px)
        defaultWidth: 425,      // Default width of the box (px)
        defaultHeight: 350, // Default height of the box (px)
        animateCaption: true,   // Enable/Disable caption animation
        flvplayer: 'swf/flvplayer.swf'
    }, options || {});

    this.anchors = [];
    $A($$('a')).each(function(el){
        if(el.rel && el.href && el.rel.test('^vidbox', 'i')) {
            el.addEvent('click', function (e) {
      e = new Event(e);
      e.stop();
      this.click(el);
            }.bind(this));
            this.anchors.push(el);
        }
}, this);

    this.overlay = new Element('div').setProperty('id', 'lbOverlay').injectInside(document.body);
    this.center = new Element('div').setProperty('id', 'lbCenter').setStyles({width: this.options.initialWidth+'px', height: this.options.initialHeight+'px', marginLeft: '-'+(this.options.initialWidth/2)+'px', display: 'none'}).injectInside(document.body);

    this.bottomContainer = new Element('div').setProperty('id', 'lbBottomContainer').setStyle('display', 'none').injectInside(document.body);
    this.bottom = new Element('div').setProperty('id', 'lbBottom').injectInside(this.bottomContainer);
    new Element('a').setProperties({id: 'lbCloseLink', href: '#'}).injectInside(this.bottom).onclick = this.overlay.onclick = this.close.bind(this);
    this.caption = new Element('div').setProperty('id', 'lbCaption').injectInside(this.bottom);
    this.number = new Element('div').setProperty('id', 'lbNumber').injectInside(this.bottom);
    new Element('div').setStyle('clear', 'both').injectInside(this.bottom);

    var nextEffect = this.nextEffect.bind(this);
    this.fx = {
        overlay: this.overlay.effect('opacity', {duration: 500}).hide(),
        center: this.center.effects({duration: 500, transition: Fx.Transitions.sineInOut, onComplete: nextEffect}),
        bottom: this.bottom.effect('margin-top', {duration: 400})
    };

},

click: function(link) {

        return this.open (link.href, link.title, link.rel);

},
open: function(sLinkHref, sLinkTitle, sLinkRel) {
    this.href = sLinkHref;
    this.title = sLinkTitle;
    this.rel = sLinkRel;
    this.position();
    this.setup();
    this.video(this.href);
    this.top = Window.getScrollTop() + (Window.getHeight() / 15);
    this.center.setStyles({top: this.top+'px', display: ''});
    this.fx.overlay.start(0.8);
    this.step = 1;
    this.center.setStyle('background','#fff url(loading.gif) no-repeat center');
    this.caption.innerHTML = this.title;
    this.fx.center.start({'height': [this.options.contentsHeight]});
},

setup: function(){
    var aDim = this.rel.match(/[0-9]+/g);
    this.options.contentsWidth = (aDim && (aDim[0] > 0)) ? aDim[0] : this.options.defaultWidth;
    this.options.contentsHeight = (aDim && (aDim[1] > 0)) ? aDim[1] : this.options.defaultHeight;

},

position: function(){
this.overlay.setStyles({'top': window.getScrollTop()+'px', 'height': window.getHeight()+'px'});
},

video: function(sLinkHref){
    if (sLinkHref.match(/youtube\.com\/watch/i)) {
  this.flash = true;
        var hRef = sLinkHref;
        var videoId = hRef.split('=');
        this.videoID = videoId[1];
        this.so = new SWFObject("http://www.youtube.com/v/"+this.videoID, "flvvideo", this.options.contentsWidth, this.options.contentsHeight, "0");
        this.so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
    }
    else if (sLinkHref.match(/metacafe\.com\/watch/i)) {
  this.flash = true;
        var hRef = sLinkHref;
        var videoId = hRef.split('/');
        this.videoID = videoId[4];
        this.so = new SWFObject("http://www.metacafe.com/fplayer/"+this.videoID+"/.swf", "flvvideo", this.options.contentsWidth, this.options.contentsHeight, "0");
        this.so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
    }
    else if (sLinkHref.match(/google\.com\/videoplay/i)) {
  this.flash = true;
        var hRef = sLinkHref;
        var videoId = hRef.split('=');
        this.videoID = videoId[1];
        this.so = new SWFObject("http://video.google.com/googleplayer.swf?docId="+this.videoID+"&hl=en", "flvvideo", this.options.contentsWidth, this.options.contentsHeight, "0");
        this.so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
    }
    else if (sLinkHref.match(/ifilm\.com\/video/i)) {
      this.flash = true;
        var hRef = sLinkHref;
        var videoId = hRef.split('video/');
        this.videoID = videoId[1];
        this.so = new SWFObject("http://www.ifilm.com/efp", "flvvideo", this.options.contentsWidth, this.options.contentsHeight, "0", "#000");
        this.so.addVariable("flvbaseclip", this.videoID+"&");
        this.so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
    }
    else if (sLinkHref.match(/\.mov/i)) {
      this.flash = false;
        if (navigator.plugins && navigator.plugins.length) {
      this.other ='<object id="qtboxMovie" type="video/quicktime" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" data="'+sLinkHref+'" width="'+this.options.contentsWidth+'" height="'+this.options.contentsHeight+'"><param name="src" value="'+sLinkHref+'" /><param name="scale" value="aspect" /><param name="controller" value="true" /><param name="autoplay" value="true" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" /><param name="enablejavascript" value="true" /></object>';
  } else {
    this.other = '<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" width="'+this.options.contentsWidth+'" height="'+this.options.contentsHeight+'" id="qtboxMovie"><param name="src" value="'+sLinkHref+'" /><param name="scale" value="aspect" /><param name="controller" value="true" /><param name="autoplay" value="true" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" /><param name="enablejavascript" value="true" /></object>';
  }
    }
    else if (sLinkHref.match(/\.wmv/i) || sLinkHref.match(/\.asx/i)) {
    this.flash = false;
     this.other = '<object NAME="Player" WIDTH="'+this.options.contentsWidth+'" HEIGHT="'+this.options.contentsHeight+'" align="left" hspace="0" type="application/x-oleobject" CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"><param NAME="URL" VALUE="'+sLinkHref+'"><param><param NAME="AUTOSTART" VALUE="false"></param><param name="showControls" value="true"></param><embed WIDTH="'+this.options.contentsWidth+'" HEIGHT="'+this.options.contentsHeight+'" align="left" hspace="0" SRC="'+sLinkHref+'" TYPE="application/x-oleobject" AUTOSTART="false"></embed></object>'
    }
    else if (sLinkHref.match(/\.flv/i)) {
     this.flash = true;
     this.so = new SWFObject(this.options.flvplayer+"?file="+sLinkHref, "flvvideo", this.options.contentsWidth, this.options.contentsHeight, "0", "#000");
    }
    else {
      this.flash = true;
        this.videoID = sLinkHref;
        this.so = new SWFObject(this.videoID, "flvvideo", this.options.contentsWidth, this.options.contentsHeight, "0");
    }
},

nextEffect: function(){
    switch (this.step++){
    case 1:
        this.fx.center.start({'width': [this.options.contentsWidth], 'marginLeft': [this.options.contentsWidth/-2]});
        break;
        this.step++;
    case 2:
        this.center.setStyle('background','#fff');
        this.flash ? this.so.write(this.center) : this.center.setHTML(this.other) ;
        this.bottomContainer.setStyles({top: (this.top + this.center.clientHeight)+'px', height: '0px', marginLeft: this.center.style.marginLeft, width: this.options.contentsWidth+'px',display: ''});
        if (this.options.animateCaption){
            this.fx.bottom.set(-this.bottom.offsetHeight);
            this.bottomContainer.style.height = '';
            this.fx.bottom.start(0);
            break;
        }
        this.bottomContainer.style.height = '';
        this.step++;
    }
},

close: function(){
    this.fx.overlay.start(0);
    this.center.style.display = this.bottomContainer.style.display = 'none';
    this.center.innerHTML = '';
    return false;
}
```

};

window.addEvent('domready', Videobox.init.bind(Videobox));

Comment: I can't even open the magazine due to the number of JS errors I'm getting in Firefox.

Comment: I'm accessing just fine through Waterfox, IE9 and Chrome

Comment: Here are the errors: http://imgur.com/bxevHoy

Comment: I fixed the first and last error but the middle one from the VidBox.js is written in the js file that I just downloaded for the popup box.

Comment: I get an error in IE saying jQuery is undefined. I guess a lot of other script issues could be resolved you just go through your errors and fix them. Later scripts will not execute properly if there is an earlier error.

Answer (score 0):

There are many js plugins that does the work.

Here are few:

[VideoBox](http://videobox-lb.sourceforge.net/)
[ShadowBox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/)

Comment: I tried the VideoBox just now. It's still opening into a new url.

Comment: I have tried 5 different shaddow boxes etc. They should have all worked but are for some reason taking me to the direct link instead of calling up the JS file. I know I am calling it up correctly so I don't know what is going on.

Comment: if u can post code we would know whats going wrong and can help.

Answer (score 0):

Both [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) and [FancyBox2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) support youtube video. I've used Fancbox for youtube videos before and its pretty simple.

Comment: I have tried 5 different shaddow boxes etc. They should have all worked but are for some reason taking me to the direct link instead of calling up the JS file. I know I am calling it up correctly so I don't know what is going on.

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors? Looking the screen shots that @HighParkCoder posted. You might not have loaded jquery.